# Postgres Stored Procedure Call Procedure and Fetch Query together

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 (p_cursor INOUT refcursor)
AS $$
BEGIN

OPEN p_cursor FOR
  SELECT emp_name
    FROM employee
   WHERE exchange_code = 'CSE'
     AND TIMESTAMP =
                    (SELECT MAX (TIMESTAMP)
                       FROM employee
                      WHERE exchange_code = 'CSE');
DELETE FROM employee
     WHERE exchange_code = 'CSE';
END;
$$
Language  plpgsql;
```

CALL procedure1('curs'); --> Returns a single column with value 'curs'

FETCH ALL FROM curs; --> fetches actual data

Running these two together fetches the result, but when i try to put these statements into another procedure to execute sequentially, I am not able to do that..

Issue I am facing is, I am not able to create a procedure for sequentially call these two statements,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PRECEDURE procedure2()
AS $$
 DECLARE
  curs refcursor := 'curs';
BEGIN
  CALL fno_nb_contfileftch1('curs');
  FETCH ALL FROM curs;
END;
$$
Language  plpgsql;
```

This give an error,
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 7: FETCH ALL FROM curs;
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 180

how to make this work... (postgresql version 13.2)

Comment: You'd need a destination for the values you fetch. Your use case cries for a function that `RETURNS SETOF whatever`, so don't use a procedure.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the update..I have recently started on postgres stored procedure..can you please help me what should I change in the above existing code..

Comment: As I said, use a function. I won't write your code for you.